# How to calculate lat lng in spidermode?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps, coordinates

I have center point and the length, I want to calculate or find the other location based on the center point and length(no. of other location) so the result would look something like this?

[image]

Language: Javascript (React native). Please help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Geolib](https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib) library. This library will provide you functions to workaround the geolocations.